# Ruff Ignore Inline or Function Rule Check

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruff

I am using `ruff==0.0.265` I have a single function I expect to have complexity and do not wish to change that.

```
src/exceptions.py:109:5: C901 `convert_py4j_exception` is too complex (11 > 10)
src/exceptions.py:109:5: PLR0911 Too many return statements (10 > 6)
```

How do I ignore a specific rule with ruff on a single function `convert_py4j_exception()`. I do not want to turn it off completly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an ignore comment at the end of a line.
In this case I would assume it has to be added on the `def` line.
The ruff error does indicate what line is meant though. (109 in your case)

So for example you could do:

```py
def convert_py4j_exception():  # noqa: C901 PLR0911
    ...
```

In general you should avoid disabling linting rules and try to refactor your code instead.

I have to do it so rarely, that I always need to look it up :-D Hopefully next time I will find my answer here.

Comment: Adding it to the `def` line only suppresses ruff on that line. I would also like to suppress ruff on a block of code and have not found how to do that yet.